# Secure connection from IP address w/ WP 4.1 to wordpress server?

Tags: wordpress, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new to wordpress, so please bear with me.

We're hosting a wordpress 4.1 installation internally in our Windows Server, within our network; our WP url is http://ourserver:2020/wordpress/wp-login.php We're behind a firewall and I don't have access to it.

Initially, it wouldn't connect at all from the start, so I added the following and it works:

```
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'proxy.ourcompany.com');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '8080');
define ('WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS', 'api.wordpress.org, downloads.wordpress.org, planet.wordpress.org, akismet.com');
```

But after I download and install a theme, I get the same error 3 times, but in different lines of **update.php**:

`WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\update.php on line 119`

So I'm thinking that here particularly, WP requires a secure HTTPS connection to WP's server. That has to be the only explanation because it already connected to WP to download the theme.

I also added the following, but nothing:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL', false);
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', false);
```

So two questions:

- Is it possible that the error has to with the WP installation requiring a secure connection?
- How can I connect securely from an IP to the wordpress server? From what I've read, I can't install an SSL certificate if I don't have a domain name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not with WordPress wanting to connect back to itself securely. It is trying to make a call to https://wordpress.org. The Defines you added are actually making it worse.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL', false);
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', false);
```

I would remove them.

As ot the problem, I seem to remember Andrew Nacin talking about the fact that they were migrating all calls back to wordpress.org to https calls. While it is possible that it is your setup, my guess is that it is your firewall. For some reason it is blocking access to https://wordpress.org. This can easily be verified by checking the firewall logs. If that is the case, you will need to figure out how to allow your site to dial out in order to use the theme and/or plugin installer. Also, you won't be able to use the automatic updater.

All of these tasks can be done manually, so it's not the end of the world if you can't unblock it. But it will be an inconvenience.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Thanks. If my firewall is blocking access to https://wordpress.org, would it mean that I can't access https://wordpress.org via a browser either?

Comment: In theory, yes. https//wordpress.org. A better test would be to use wget or curl from the command line on the box running WordPress. see if you can hit https://wordpress.org from that.

Comment: I was able to access https://wordpress.org through a browser. I don't have unix, so I used `ping` and I was able to access the site (wordpress.org). Remember that the site was able to access http://wordpress.org since I was able to download and install a theme. But it seems that after it installs, it tries to access https://wordpress.org and that's when the errors pop up. Does wget check if I can access an https site?

Comment: Oing only tells you if your machine can route packets ICMP packets, not HTTP packets, to the server. wget https://wordpress.org will tell you if you are able to fetch a webpage from the secure site. You need to do this on the machine that is running your WordPress. However, honestly, the easiest thing to do may simply be contact your network administrator and ask them if there is some reason why it's failing. If it's a firewall issue then they can see it in their log files. If they've got nothing, then you know that it's not the firewall and can proceed to debugging it.

Comment: You're right. Called wget from server and received `(try: 3)  http://wordpress.org/ Connecting to wordpress.org|66.155.40.249|:80... failed`. So to summarize, my WP installation connects to HTTP to download the theme, and after download/installation tries to connect to HTTPS and this is where it fails.

Comment: Yep, time to talk to the Network Admins. (Take them cookies, they love that.)  :)